# jQuery - Way to delete selected object in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hi everyone, I have created a multidimensional array which is dynamically will change with different depths.That why I'm not use usual way to create a static looping process.

So,the problem here I can't to delete selected object in that array.

**Example array before delete particular object**

```
var data = [
  {
    id:"43",
    text: 'Parent 1'
  },
  {
    id:"55",
    text: 'Parent 2',
    nodes: [
      {
        id:"57",
        text: 'Child 1',
        nodes: [
          {
            id:"56",
            text: 'Child sub 2'
          },
          {
            id:"50",
            text: 'Child sub 3'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id:"47",
    text: 'Parent 3',
    nodes: [
      {
        id:"48",
        text: 'Child 2'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**if I selected setence object for example,current array will remain as below**

```
  {
    id:"50",
    text: 'Child sub 3'
  }
```

**Expected result**

```
   var data = [
          {
            id:"43",
            text: 'Parent 1'
          },
          {
            id:"55",
            text: 'Parent 2',
            nodes: [
              {
                id:"57",
                text: 'Child 1',
                nodes: [
                  {
                    id:"56",
                    text: 'Child sub 2'
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id:"47",
            text: 'Parent 3',
            nodes: [
              {
                id:"48",
                text: 'Child 2'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

The example code in my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/youo8uht/12/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, assuming your data format doesn't change:

```
// using your previously-defined data variable

var query = {
  key: 'id',
  value: 50
};

function removeMatchedObjectFromArray(source, query) {
  query.parent = query.parent || source;
  for (var key in source) {
    if (!source.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      continue;
    }
    if (typeof source[key] === 'object') {
      if (source[key] && source[key] instanceof Array) {
        query.parent = source[key];
      }
      removeMatchedObjectFromArray(source[key], query);
    } else if (key == query.key && source[key] == query.value) {
      query.parent.splice(query.parent.indexOf(source), 1);
    }
  }
}

removeMatchedObjectFromArray(data, query);
```

Comment: Thank @SimianAngel, its working if not exist another array in every object as my example array. So,that is my problem now,can't expand more array attribute on every object. Example on my latest jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/youo8uht/13/